# Python - How do I get and use the data from firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

Here is my updated code with the revisions. I only added the `user_num = 1` to try to avoid the unsupported operand error I was getting , but that didn't work either.

**.py**

```
class MetropolisApp(App):
    user_num = 1
    database_url = 'https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/'

    def build(self):
        self.my_firebase = MyFirebase()
        return ControlScreens()

    def on_start(self):
        user_num_req = requests.get("https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/user_num.json")
        self.user_num = user_num_req.json()

        db = requests.get('https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/' + str(self.user_num) + '.json')
        #print(db.ok)
        data = json.loads(db.content.decode())
        #print(data)


    def post(self, firstname, lastname, email, username, password):

        self.user_num += 1

        # Make a python dictionary
        fname_data = {"fname": firstname}
        lname_data = {"lname": lastname}
        email_data = {"email": email}
        user_id = {"userid": username}
        user_pw = {"userpw": password}

        # Send the python dictionary
        requests.post(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=fname_data)
        requests.post(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=lname_data)
        requests.post(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=email_data)
        requests.post(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=user_id)
        requests.post(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=user_pw)

    def in_database(self, firstname, lastname, email, username, password):

        fname_data = {"fname": firstname}
        lname_data = {"lname": lastname}
        email_data = {"email": email}
        user_id = {"userid": username}
        user_pw = {"userpw": password}

        requests.patch(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=fname_data)
        requests.patch(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=lname_data)
        requests.patch(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=email_data)
        requests.patch(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=user_id)
        requests.patch(url=self.database_url + str(self.user_num) + '.json', json=user_pw)

        check_request = requests.get(
            'https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="userid"&equalTo="%s"' % self.root.ids[
                'user_login'].text)
        print(check_request.json())

        # print(self.root.ids)
```

Not sure if the .kv file is needed, but here is the main code in which I am having errors.

Edited Database

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple concepts to understand here. The first is the **rule** system of Firebase's real-time database. The rule system dictates what kind of reads/writes to the database are allowed. An important part of the rule system is using `indexes` to tell Firebase that you want to be able to query your data by a certain parameter. For example, you need to query your database by the `userid` parameter. In your rules tab of your real-time database, you need to tell Firebase to let you 'indexOn' the 'userid' parameter, like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true, // Note - this allows all reads from anyone anywhere. only use for testing
    ".write": true, // same comment
    ".indexOn": ["userid"] // You can allow multiple indexOns by doing ["userid","foo","bar"]
  }
}
```

The ".indexOn" portion above is part of your top level rules (`/` in your database), and you want to index on data that is inside some special identifier (`/special_identifier/userid`). The special identifier for your test user is `2` in this case.

Now that you are allowing your database to be queried by the `userid` parameter, you need to actually send a request using python to query it. The next concept here is sending some special arguments in the URL of your get request (read Firebase's documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)). In this case, you need to try to get data from your top level (`/`) location, and **orderBy** `userid` and only return values **equalTo** `self.root.ids['user_login'].text`

Your URL in this case would be:

`'https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="userid"&equalTo="%s"'%self.root.ids['user_login'].text`

Notice how you use the `?` character to specify you're going to send some special parameters, and the `&` means another special parameter is coming. Also make sure your values that you are ordering-by or equaling-to are surrounded in `"` (assuming their strings in your database, which they are at the moment).

When you do a get request to that URL, either it will return the data for that user, or an empty dictionary.

```
check_request = requests.get('https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="userid"&equalTo="%s"'%self.root.ids['user_login'].text)
print(check_request.json()) # If this has data, the user exists, if it's an empty dictionary, {}, the user doesn't exist
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me Erik. I actually just finished watching your video and I was able to do it a little earlier lol. But thank you for the extra pointers I had no idea about. My final question however, is that whenever I do click the login button, everything in the database is replaced with the new user information instead of adding a new user. Should I be using something other than `requests.patch` ?

Comment: For example, if ID 1 was in the database with data, and I wanted to add a new user, ID 1 would be replaced with the new user data instead of adding an ID 2 to the database.

Comment: Good to hear. Are you making sure that you're updating `self.user_num` when doing your patch requests? If `self.user_num` is always 1, you'll just overwrite your data.

Comment: yep, just +=1 to your `self.user_num` variable. Or if you want your database to keep track of `self.user_num`, add a new field to your top level of your database. Then use a get request to retrieve the user num in the database. Then make sure you do a patch request and +=1 to what's in the database.

Comment: it has to do with this. I'm realizing that because my user_num variable is set to 0, when I add the 1 yes, it does add another user ID. However, when I close the app and start it back over, because it's at 0 it does the same thing and overwrites previous data

Comment: you should no longer be setting it to 0 or anything inside your python code. You should only be reading/writing the value from the database

Comment: how would I go about fixing that? I can add as many users as I need to but once I close the app it starts back over

Comment: In your code, do you have a line like `self.user_num = 0`?

Comment: Under my app class as a normal variable I have `user_num = 0` and under my function that posts the data to the database, I have `self.user_num += 1` for every time the sign up button is clicked

Comment: Right, so everytime you start your app up, it sets user_num to 0. That's not what you want - you want your user_num to be set to whatever is in the database. so instead of `user_num = ` in your start up function, do something like `user_num_req = requests.get("https://metropolis-58211.firebaseio.com/user_num.json")` then `user_num = user_num_req.json()`.

Comment: in my `on_start()` function or my `MetropolosApp(App)` ? Because when I try it in my main app class I get an error, `self.user_num += 1
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'` and when I try it in my `on_start()` function `self.user_num` can't find the `user_num` variable

Comment: Did the `user_num_req` work ok? If you print `user_num_req.json()` does it print what you expect?

Comment: Yeah it returns True. And the `user_num_req.json()` returns None because I don't have anything in the database at the moment

Comment: Ok, well put something in the database so that your `user_num_req.json()` actually returns a number for you. Then in your `on_start` function, do `user_num_req = requests.get(...)` and `self.user_num = user_num_req.json()`. `user_num_req.json()` will be None until you put something in your database for it to actually read

Comment: for some reason it still returns None. And I keep getting the unsupported operand error. I'll post the code so you can see what I have going on

Comment: not sure if i'm missing a major connection between my database and python code or not

Comment: Post a little screenshot of your database too so we can make sure you have the `user_num` field in there correctly

Comment: Added. Not sure if post or patch makes a difference but I'm using post for now because I thought patch was what was overwriting my data .

Comment: @LearningtoCodee your screenshot is helpful. Your get request will always return None since you don't have a field in there for your `user_num`. Hover your mouse over `metropolis-58211` and click the `+` button. Then make a new field named `user_num` and set it equal to `0`. Now your `user_num_req` will read that! Before it wasn't reading anything

Comment: like the new database I just posted ? Yeah now the url makes sense because there was no user_num in the database for the url to find.

Comment: Right. Now you can read that to set your `self.user_num` variable as opposed to setting `self.user_num = 0` in your app somewhere! Just make sure everytime you make a new user you update the `user_num` field in the database. I show that near the end of video 9.

Comment: should I have the `user_num` still equal to one in my main app class ? or equal to something else

Comment: Think about it - if you set user_num to anything explicitly in your app, then no matter how many users you add you will always be resetting it. That's no good!

Comment: haha true that was a dumb question. It should be `user_num = user_num_request.json()` correct ? But would that still be in my main app class?

Comment: `user_num` or `self.user_num` -- I don't know exactly cause I'm not looking at your code, but you should know which it needs to be. It can be anywhere you need it to be as long as it's paired with the `get` request

Comment: I have it as `self.user_num` because I need it to update as every user. However every time I click sign up the regular ID is being updated by 1, but now the user_num we added in the database. That stays at 2. and because of that when I restart the app, instead of adding more users my first user is being overwritten and so on

Comment: are you increasing the value in the database each time you sign a user up?

Comment: yeah I'm still watching your video trying to figure out how to do it